# .data() binding only first element

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am building an epidemic simulation using D3's force-directed diagram.

When a transmission event occurs, I want to move a circle from the transmitter to the newly infected individual.

**PROBLEM: Only the first element is created and moved according to the bound data.**

First, I gather the coordinates:

```
    xyCoords = getPathogen_xyCoords(newInfections);
```

Where xyCoords looks like the following:

```
{receiverX: newInfections[i].x, receiverY: newInfections[i].y, transmitterX: newInfections[i].infectedBy.x, transmitterY: newInfections[i].infectedBy.y}
```

Then I create the circles and bind them to xyCoords:

```
d3.select(".svg").append("circle")
    .attr("class", "pathogen")


d3.selectAll(".pathogen")
    .data(xyCoords)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.transmitterX})
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.transmitterY})
    .attr("r", 4)
    .style("fill", "green")
```

Finally, the circle is moved with a transition:

```
d3.selectAll(".pathogen")
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.receiverX} )
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.receiverY} );
```

EDIT: The game has been up for a few months now and doing quite well! Check it out at http://vax.herokuapp.com!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem...

At creation of the circles, I was not "entering" new circles to be associated with the newly bound data.

It was displaying only the first element on bind because there was only one circle to begin with.

Creation of the circles now looks like this:

```
xyCoords = getPathogen_xyCoords(newInfections);

var pathogen = svg.selectAll(".pathogen")
    .data(xyCoords)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "pathogen")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.transmitterX })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.transmitterY })
    .attr("r", 4)
    .style("fill", "green")
```